Salt-stack: unable to find mounted network drive from salt-master to salt-minion
I have a salt master and a salt-minion (windows server 2019) that i am trying to use a salt-state to install some applications. As part of this install i want to copy a number of files from a mounted network drive on the local storage of the salt-minion.
My network drive is mounted on W and i can get to it fine on the server, copy files etc.
My issue is commands run from the salt-master get the error that there is no W drive.
salt My_SERVER cmd.run "ls 'W:/FOLDER/'" shell=powershell
MY_SERVER:
    ls : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'W' does not exist.
    At line:1 char:1
    + ls 'W:/FOLDER/'
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (W:String) [Get-ChildItem], DriveNotFoundException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand 

I have tried adding runas and using the user I login to the server with but I get no output. If I run a whoami command from the master to the minion it's the nt user. I have tried changing salt to run as MY_USER but it doesn't seem to use the config after a restart.
What am I missing to be able to remotely execute a command that uses this network drive?
EDIT:
I have just tried creating the mount on cmd with salt which also fails, details are below:
salt MY_SERVER cmd.run "net use W: \\10.192.68.68\Folder /persistent:Yes /user:ftp_user Password123"

MY_SERVER:
    System error 67 has occurred.
    
    The network name cannot be found.


This same command works if i run it locally on MY_SERVER. running a whoami locally and remotely with salt gives me the same output.

Which server is "the server"? Or are both master and minion installed on the same server?

MY_SERVER is the salt minion. Im running the command from my master

I haven't done the exact same thing using Salt but have done something similar and my notes may help.

Set up a local user (fsuser in the example below) on the host serving your files (FILE_SERVER below)
On MY_SERVER set up a credential for the SYSTEM user for accessing the file share on the serving host (you need psexec for this)
$ psexec -s cmd
> cmdkey /add:FILE_SERVER /user:localhost\fsuser /pass:<password>


Access the files using a UNC path \\FILE_SERVER\ShareName

There is a workaround if you must access the files using a network drive (e.g. W:)

Instead of psexec, you can use Salt.

Thanks for helping. I have my fsuser on the file_server, and on my_server ive run your cmdkey command but still when i try to list something from the mounted directory with either the unc path or just the W: path im getting the same error
